# CaptureChangeMysql Json flow file contains "{0}" OR "{}" instead of "TRUE" or "FALSE" boolean value. How should I convert as Boolean value

Tags: apache-nifi

[image: JsonTreeReader_AvroSchema UpdateRecord Processor][image: CSVWriter OutPut Updaterecord processor]

```html
[ {
  "id" : 57592,
  "code" : "village1023",
  "created_by_id" : null,
  "created_date" : "Tue Mar 31 23:08:47 IST 2020",
  "l_village_name" : "village1023",
  "modified_by_id" : 70806,
  "modified_date" : "Tue Mar 31 23:08:47 IST 2020",
  "name" : "village1023",
  "status" : "{0}",
  "taluk_id" : 386
} ]
```

[image]Any suggestion on how could I convert the value received from JSON as "status" : "{0}" as "TRUE" for the MySQL value "1" in bit data type.

Comment: It's not clear what you need.

Comment: In my input JSON from CaptureChangeMySQL processor I am getting value {0} for MySQL value 1. I need to convert JSON value to "TRUE" and insert it into destination table using PutDatabaseRecord processor. How should I covert this.

Comment: I got the expected result, I made mistake in the expression. It should be ${field.value:equals("{0}"):ifElse("TRUE","FALSE")} in "UpdateRecord" processor.

Comment: @daggett  I was trying to create a mirror database of MySQL. For this, I am using "CaptureChangeMySQL". Once I insert or update a record in my source database I will get JSON flow file from "CaptureChangeMySQL" with a value "{0}"  for the "status" column in MySQL which is of data type "BIT". I was trying to convert it as boolean in the "UpdateRecord" processor. It was not converted since i was using "status" instead of "field.value" in the expression  ${field.value:equals("{0}"):ifElse("TRUE","FALSE")}. I found the issue and fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the JSON value content "{0}" in to true, we can update the content of the flow file using ReplaceText processor, so you can simply use the ReplaceText processor to achieve the reported scenario but still it have its own limitations. Please check and proceed further.

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ReplaceText/

Comment: I am using the "UpdateRecord" processor with the expression as below, but I am getting always the value in the else part. How should I match the value. 
 ${status:equals("[{0}]"):ifElse("TRUE","FALSE") }

Comment: @GaneshKumar - In the update attribute processor, we can use advance option to match the attribute value based on the condition rule. For example, add rule like if status equals "{0}", we can add attribute  with value TRUE and add another rule for False condition and set same attribute name as same as given for True condition.

Comment: I tried adding a rule in the UpdateAttribute "advance" option, but the value is not yet changed. I am getting the same value {0}. The rule mentioned below. 
${status:equals("{0}")}. Please confirm whether the expression being used is correct to match the value of JSON.

Comment: May be the given expression not a valid one, try out the expression  ${status:contains("0")} and check whether the output is correct and check out the mistake made in previous statement.

Comment: Still I am getting same value as {0} instead of "TRUE".

Comment: Did you checked the "status" attribute used in the expression ? whether it has the correct value

Comment: Please find the attached screenshot for expression.

Comment: @GaneshKumar - We need to store "status" attribute value separately using  "UpdateAttribute" processor, Then we need to validate that "status" attribute in the rule expression. it seems you didn't have any separate attribute for "status".

http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-update-attribute-nar/1.11.4/org.apache.nifi.processors.attributes.UpdateAttribute/additionalDetails.html

Comment: I got the expected result, I made mistake in the expression. It should be ${field.value:equals("{0}"):ifElse("TRUE","FALSE")}  in "UpdateRecord" processor.

Answer (score 0):

I got the expected result, I made mistake in the expression. It should be ${field.value:equals("{0}"):ifElse("TRUE","FALSE")}  in "UpdateRecord" processor.

[Doumentation - Example 5 - Use Expression Language to Modify Value](http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.11.4/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.UpdateRecord/additionalDetails.html)